# WSO2 EI and WSO2 Developer - Setup an ESB Proxy with http basic authentication

Tags: wso2, basic-authentication, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 EI 6.3.0 and WSO2 Developer Studio 3.8.0.
I'm working with an ESB Project and a Proxy Service inside it.

The Proxy service is a simple pass through service;
it receives a request from a webapp and forward it to a
Soap Web Service, gets the response from the WS and gives
it back to the web app.

I realized this configuration following this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/3OsuGhEMQgc

The setup is very simple, everything worked fine until I found
a web service whose endpoint has http basic authentication.

I made it work thanks to this article:
https://medium.com/@Jenananthan/wso2-esb-how-to-invoke-basic-auth-protected-endpoint-service-5bcdd8290cb4

Here follows the xml that describes the proxy service:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="ProxyWithBasicAuth" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable" transports="https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <endpoint name="endpoint_urn_uuid_xxxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-1111-234567892345">
            <address trace="disable" uri="https://here.goes.the.uri.of.the.ws.endpoint"/>
        </endpoint>
        <inSequence>
            <property value="this_is_the_username" name="username" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property value="this_is_the_password" name="password" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="fn:concat($ctx:username,':',$ctx:password)" name="credentials" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode($ctx:credentials))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

So, this configuration (xml file) **is working**, but I wrote all
the section that enables basic auth without using any visual or drag and drop element of the gui.

**My questions are:**
**1) is this the right way to setup basic auth on a proxy service?**
**2) is there any gui (drag and drop) element that allows to do this setup visually?**

Note: I do not need to struggle with basic authentication between
"clients" and the ESB Proxy Service; this question is about basic
authentication between ESB Proxy Service and an "external" web service.

Comment: Can you help to make it work?
i copied your proxy but  i dont know how to test it ?  it's working whether it has basic auth or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done is correct. To invoke a service secured with Basic Auth, we just have to set the Authorization header to the message. You could use Header Mediator[1] or the Property mediator (as you have already used) to do that. There is no special Mediator (or a GUI element in the Tool) specifically designed for setting the Authorization header.

Btw, you could consider storing passwords in the secure-vault[2] rather than having it in plain text in the Synapse configuration.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Header+Mediator
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+Passwords+in+the+ESB+profile

Comment: Second the secure vault part, was the first thing I thought of as well.