# How to Configure HTTP Basic Auth for WSO2 EI proxy service

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

i am using WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.5.0 (lastest)

I need to enable  HTTP Basic Authentication through a Proxy Service (SOAP, REST)

I have tried below resource  - 
[WSO2 EI and WSO2 Developer - Setup an ESB Proxy with http basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54769567/wso2-ei-and-wso2-developer-setup-an-esb-proxy-with-http-basic-authentication)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="ProxyWithBasicAuth" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable" transports="https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <endpoint name="endpoint_urn_uuid_xxxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-1111-234567892345">
            <address trace="disable" uri="https://here.goes.the.uri.of.the.ws.endpoint"/>
        </endpoint>
        <inSequence>
            <property value="this_is_the_username" name="username" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property value="this_is_the_password" name="password" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="fn:concat($ctx:username,':',$ctx:password)" name="credentials" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode($ctx:credentials))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

But it does not work? 
i was expecting when i send wrong credentials,

The Proxy service would give me error?

below is the way i sending request : 
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to call a service with a proxy server inbetween or just a service that needs basic auth? If its with a proxy, you have to set it in axis2.xml as well. If not enable wire log https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Debugging+Mediation and check if the header is set.

Comment: <transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender">
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <!--<parameter name="warnOnHTTP500" locked="false">*</parameter>-->
        <!--parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">localhost</parameter-->
        <!--<parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">3128</parameter>-->
        <!--<parameter name="http.nonProxyHosts" locked="false">localhost|moon|sun</parameter>-->
    </transportSender>

Comment: @Martin Hald in axis2.xml these line of config code was commented?

should be uncomment this ?

Comment: If there´s a proxy server between your wso2 and the backend, yes then you should uncomment and configure it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, your requirement is to secure the proxy service, which will be invoked as REST, using Basic Auth. It is recommended to secure a proxy service using security policies when it is used as SOAP [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Applying+Security+to+a+Proxy+Service). However, if you need to enable HTTP Basic Auth with a proxy service, you will need to write the custom implementation to authenticate the user, as it is not supported by default from the ESB. One of the following approaches can be used to achieve your requirement.

1. Implement **an API** **which is secured with Basic Auth** and call the proxy service from that API. API handler implementation can be used to implement the authentication. Please refer [[2]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+APIs#SecuringAPIs-BasicAuthUsingaBasicAuthhandler) for API handler implementation.
2. Use a **synapse handler** to process the authentication prior to the proxy service invocation. Refer [[3]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Working+with+Synapse+Handlers) for synapse handler implementation. **handleRequestInFlow()** method of the synapse handler will be called prior to the ESB proxy service. Therefore, we can have the custom authentication implementation within handleRequestInFlow() of the handler and allow/restrict the proxy calls.

[1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Applying+Security+to+a+Proxy+Service) - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Applying+Security+to+a+Proxy+Service

[2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+APIs#SecuringAPIs-BasicAuthUsingaBasicAuthhandler) - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+APIs#SecuringAPIs-BasicAuthUsingaBasicAuthhandler

[3](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Working+with+Synapse+Handlers) - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Working+with+Synapse+Handlers

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-add-http-basic-authentication.html).
I think key should be corrected as Authorization instead of Proxy-Authorization.

Comment: i tried it, 
But how can i test basic auth ? 
When i send request with/without basic auth. it still works